# 6 bytes timestamp to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I use 3rd party API. According to its specification the following

```
  byte[] timestamp = new byte[] {185, 253, 177, 161, 51, 1}
```

represents *Number of milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970 when the message 
was generated for transmission*

The issue is that I don't know how it could be translated into DateTime.

I've tried

```
DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
long milliseconds = BitConverter.ToUInt32(timestamp, 0);
var result =  Epoch + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds);
```

The result is  {2/1/1970 12:00:00 AM}, but year 2012 is expected.

Comment: Does `timestamp` uses little endian, or native endian?

Comment: All data uses the little-endian byte ordering.

Comment: Is the expected result really 2012? I get `14.11.2011 10:49:16`

Comment: You are using BitConverter.ToUInt32() which certainly won't be helping...that will only look at bytes [0...3] (i.e. 32 bits)

Comment: How does this API handle dates before the start of the epoch? Does it thread the MSB of the last byte as a sign bit? Or does it simply not support such dates?

Comment: To CodeInChaos, actually today's date 4/11/2012 is expected. Each message has the timestamp. The data was received today. But your result seems to me correct. Maybe the api is being tested now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `timestamp` uses little endian format. I also left out parameter validation.

```
long GetLongLE(byte[] buffer,int startIndex,int count)
{
  long result=0;
  long multiplier=1;
  for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
  {
    result += buffer[startIndex+i]*multiplier;
    multiplier *= 256;
  }
  return result;
}

long milliseconds = GetLongLE(timestamp, 0, 6);
```

Comment: There's a thing called BitConverter.ToInt64

Comment: @atornblad 1) You'd need to pad the array. 2) `BitConverter.ToInt64` uses native endianness. I assume the data he receives is little endian.

Answer (score 4):

```
        byte[] timestamp = new byte[] { 185, 253, 177, 161, 51, 1, 0, 0, };
        DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        ulong milliseconds = BitConverter.ToUInt64(timestamp, 0);
        var result = Epoch + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds);
```

Result is 11/14/2011

Adding padding code special for CodeInChaos:

```
    byte[] oldStamp = new byte[] { 185, 253, 177, 161, 51, 1 };
    byte[] newStamp = new byte[sizeof(UInt64)];
    Array.Copy(oldStamp, newStamp, oldStamp.Length);
```

For running on big-endian machines :

```
if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    newStamp = newStamp.Reverse().ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Does not fit the updated question. You should also include the code that adds the padding.

Comment: Now your code doesn't work at all on big endian systems, since your parsing assumes native endian, and the padding assumes litte endian.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly why `BitConverter.ToUInt64` as you use it is broken, since it assumes native endianness.

Comment: You can reverse input data if running on big endian machine. see my edit. But I think that OP can manually do such things

Comment: It's not very C#-ish but you can do Array.Resize(ref timestamp, 8) to pad the original byte array.

Comment: And Array.Reverse(timestamp) for that matter.

Comment: I've assumed, that third snippet follows after second.