# how to byte[] to timestamp

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, timestamp, enterprise-library

I've a timestamp column in my database which is used as rowversion. At the time of pulling data out of the database we get rowversion also which i converted into byte[]. Upto this stage everything works as expected.

At the time of updating data, i'd like to check (in a stored procedure), if the rowversion is the same or not, that is compare one that is being passed from code with one that is stored in database. If that differs i abort the update otherwise it updates the data.

Now my problem is, how to pass byte[] to a stored procedure. The parameter type in the stored procedure is timestamp.

**Note :** I make all the db operations in c# using enterprise library. I can't change the stored procedure or datatypes. Its restricted.

Comment: What is your byte timestamp format? Or, how does the timestamp become byte[] in the first place? Maybe it's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107625/6-bytes-timestamp-to-datetime)?

Comment: The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql

Comment: @john I get datarow from which i convert row_version to byte array like this : dr["row_version"] == DBNull.Value ? new byte[1] : (byte[])dr["row_version"];

Answer (score 3):

See code below :

```
           DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            long bNow = now.ToBinary();
            byte[] arrayNow = BitConverter.GetBytes(bNow);

            long getLong = BitConverter.ToInt64(arrayNow, 0);

            DateTime getNow = DateTime.FromBinary(getLong);

            Console.WriteLine(getNow.ToLongTimeString());
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. If so sorry for that. I just wanted to know what should be the datatype when i call the stored procedure? Which enterprise library parameter type maps to sql server timestamp?

Comment: If it is a timestamp in the database you need to use DateTime type.

Comment: No we can't. Please see below solution that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works as expected

```
public static TestMethod(....,byte[] rowVersion)
{
    .........
    dbConnection_.AddInParameter(dbcommand, "@row_version", DbType.Binary,rowVersion);
    ...........
}
```

Above code is using enterprise library. I think this will help someone.

Thank you all of you who tried to help here. Cheers..!